# How to i do typeorm and postgres upsert without find

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I am trying to upsert without find and but i don't undersand how to do it .

```
 async upsertActivity(sale: Sales, action: Actions, prevTotal: number = 0): Promise<ClientActivity> {
        let result;
        const { client, clientId, total } = sale;

        //check if client activity  already exist for client id
        const existingClientActivity = await ClientActivity.findOne({
            where: { clientId: clientId },
        });

        //update
        if (existingClientActivity?.id) {
            //when create client activity
            if (action === Actions.CREATE) {
                existingClientActivity.noOfSales = existingClientActivity.noOfSales + 1;
                existingClientActivity.totalSalesAmount = existingClientActivity.totalSalesAmount + total;
            }
            //when update client activity
            //First remove created time total then added new total
            if (action === Actions.CREATE) {
                existingClientActivity.totalSalesAmount = existingClientActivity.totalSalesAmount - prevTotal + total;
            }

            existingClientActivity.save();
        }
        //create
        else {
            const clientActivity = ClientActivity.create({
                client,
                clientId: clientId,
                noOfSales: 1,
                totalSalesAmount: total,
            });
            clientActivity.save();
        }
  
    }
```

I am trying to do it like .. but it show error.

```
    async upsert(sale: Sales, action: Actions, prevTotal: number = 0) {
        const { client, clientId, total } = sale;
        try {
            await ClientActivity.createQueryBuilder()
                .insert()
                .into(ClientActivity)
                .values({
                    client,
                    clientId,
                    noOfSales: 1,
                    totalSalesAmount: total,
                })
                .onConflict(
                    `("clientId") DO UPDATE SET 
                noOfSales = ClientActivity.noOfSales + 1,
                totalSalesAmount = CASE 
                    WHEN :action = 'create' THEN ClientActivity.totalSalesAmount + :total
                    WHEN :action = 'update' THEN ClientActivity.totalSalesAmount - :prevTotal + :total
                    ELSE ClientActivity.totalSalesAmount
                END`,
                )
                .setParameter('action', action)
                .setParameter('prevTotal', prevTotal)
                .setParameter('total', total)
                .execute();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

Error like
throw new QueryFailedError(query, parameters, err)
^
QueryFailedError: missing FROM-clause entry for table "ClientActivity"

Please if anyone know , Help me.